# optionally using a COM object that might not be registered

Tags: c#, com

My C# project references a COM library that may or may not be installed on the user's computer. My project needs to work even if that COM library is not installed, but use it if the COM library is registered.

I have no idea where to even begin researching how to accomplish this. Any suggestions?

Comment: what @SLaks said. Attempt to create the object and if it throws and exception, assume it isnt installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it deterministically, you can check that the COM object is registered in the registry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\ or HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ via the [Registry.GetValue method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue.aspx). Otherwise, use a try / catch block around the object creation and treat failure as the library not existing.